# Insiude a <form> tag all the HTML tags after a require_once are gone PHP

Tags: php, html, database, xampp

I've created a form that uses POST as the method. but inside the form there's a table that NEEDS to be update with the DB values that this form fills.
The thing is, when i call the required php file inside the table. EVERYTHING ELSE after the <?php> call is gone. all the tags, submits. and even the footer.
Any reason why?
here's my code

```
<section>
        <div class="formaGasto">
            <form action="php/addIngreso.php" method="POST" id="formulario">
                <h3>Ingresos de la vivienda</h3>
                <br>
                <br>
                <label id="labels" for="name">Nombre del ingreso: </label>
                <input id="inputs" type="text" name="name" id="name">
                <br>
                <br>
                <label id="labels" for="value">Valor del ingreso: </label>
                <input id="inputs" type="number" name="value" id="value">
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="tableFlow">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-sm" id="js">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nombre del ingreso</th>
                            <th>Valor</th>
                        </tr>
THIS IS THE CULPRIT         **<?php require_once 'php/showInfo.php';?>**
IF I REMOVE IT, EVERYTHING IS BACK
                        <br>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Nuevo" name="carga"  id="new" class="boton" onclick="addToTabla()">
                <button type="button" class="boton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
                    Guardar
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <img src="img/republicaFuturo.png" id="futuro" alt="">
        <img src="img/govcoBlue.png" id="govco" alt="">
    </footer>
```

this is my Query file

```
<?php
include 'db.php';

    $sql = "SELECT nombre, valor FROM concepto_ingreso";
    $send = $connect->prepare($sql);
    $send->execute();

    foreach ($send as $value) {
        print "<tr>";
        print "<td> $value[0] </td>";
        print "<td> $value[1] </td>";
        print "</tr>";
    }
    print "</table>";

    
    $connect = null;
?>
```

Comment: You may want to also delete the print table instruction from the showInfo.php file - this give you an unbalanced table element which maybe causing some problems.

Comment: Suggestion - When you get data, get data. Don’t print it until you are in you are in the view.

Comment: Try to turn on the error reporting

Answer (score 0):

Used a try-catch block and changed require to include.

Comment: `required` to `include` should be the only change required. You are likely including the wrong path so the include/require fails. With `require` that causes a fatal error. With `include` it will continue to execute. Permissions or path is your likely issue.